# gstreamer pipeline that was working now requiring a bunch of queue components, why?

Tags: queue, gstreamer, pipeline

I have a C program that records video and audio from a v4l2 source into flv format. I noticed that the program did not work on newer versions of ubuntu. I decided to try to run the problamatic pipeline in gst-launch and try to find the simplest pipeline that would reproduce the problem. Just focusing on the video side I have reduced it to what you see below.

So I have a gstreamer pipeline that was working:

```
gst-launch v4l2src ! tee name="vtee" ! queue ! videorate ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ffdeinterlace ! x264enc ! flvmux name="mux" ! filesink location=vid.flv vtee. ! queue ! xvimagesink
```

Now it will only work if I do this with a bunch of queue's added one after another before the xvimagesink. Although this does work I get a 2 second delay before the pipeline starts to work and i also get the message :

```
gst-launch v4l2src ! tee name="vtee" ! queue ! videorate ! ffmpegcolorspace ! ffdeinterlace ! x264enc ! flvmux name="mux" ! filesink location=vid.flv vtee. ! queue ! queue ! queue ! queue ! queue ! xvimagesink
```

Although the second pipeline above works, there is a pause before the pipeline starts running and I get the message (I don't think this system is 2 slow, its a core i7 with tons of ram):

```
Additional debug info:
gstbasesink.c(2692): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
```

Can any one explain what is happening here? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You claim that the first pipeline stopped working but you don't explain what happened.  Things stop working because something else changed:
 - version of GStreamer and submodules ?
 - version of OS ?
 - version of camera ?

It shouldn't be necessary to add a bunch of queues in a row.  In practice they will create thread boundaries and separate the part before and after across threads, and it will add the delay you see, which will affect the latency and sync.

Answer (score 0):

An old message, but the problem is still not fixed. Somewhere between `9.10` and `11.10` (I upgraded a few before noticing). I got around it by avoiding the `x264enc` and used `ffenc_mpeg4` instead.

I just noticed this note from [Gstreamer Cheat Sheet](http://wiki.oz9aec.net/index.php/Gstreamer_cheat_sheet) :

Note: We can replace `theoraenc+oggmux` with `x264enc+someothermuxer` but then the pipeline will freeze unless we make the queue [19] element in front of the `xvimagesink` leaky, i.e. `"queue leaky=1"`.

Which doesn't work for me so I'll stick with `ffenc_mpeg4`.